# POI XSSF overwriting specific cells in excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to write out to an existing excel file. I don't want to create new rows or cells, I just want to write out the value from my array into the value at row x column y. Every time I have tried this so far I can only get it to work if I create a new row. Please help!!!

```
      Integer columns = DataImport.columns_in_sheet[0];
        Integer rowNum = learnerRow + 2;

        try {
            FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream("D:/location/update.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
            wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(18);//places the start row
            XSSFCell cell = null;//places the start column
            cell = row.getCell(0);

//#########################################################################################

//#########################################################################################
            for (int j = 0; j < exportData.length; j++) {
                //sheet.createRow(rowNum+j);
                //row = sheet.getRow(rowNum+j);

                //row = sheet.getRow(rowNum+j);
                for (int i=0; i < columns;i++){

                    cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                    cell.setCellValue(exportData[j][i]);
                }
            }

            // Write the output to a file
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/location/update.xlsx");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

this code throws a null pointer because of row being null, I can only seem to get rid of the error by creating new rows. I am using XSSF formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your code snippet is not clear. It looks not logically to me.

But to avoid `NPE` while using rows and cells from present sheets, one always needs check whether the row or cell was present already or needs to be new created. This is necessary because for not present rows `Sheet.getRow` will return `null`. Also `Row.getCell` will return `null` for not present cells.

So we can do:

```
Sheet sheet = ...
Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIdx); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx); 
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellIdx); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(cellIdx);
```

Now `row` either is a row which was already present or it is a new created row. And `cell` either is a cell which was already present or it is a new created cell. Neither `row` nor `cell` will be `null`. And at first present rows/cells will be got before they were new created if not present. So present rows and cells will not be destroyed.

The same is needed in loops:

```
Sheet sheet = ...
Row row;
Cell cell;
for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < 10; rowIdx++) {
 row = sheet.getRow(rowIdx); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx);
 for (int cellIdx = 0; cellIdx < 10; cellIdx++) {
  cell = row.getCell(cellIdx); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(cellIdx);
  // do something with cell
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this I have been smashing my head over something that a little know how solved in seconds. Amended my code and it is all working,